# Unity - Microphone stops recording after 10-20 seconds while set to last 1h

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, record, microphone

I am working on a game where you control the character with the loudness of your voice. After working on it for a while I got everything to work fine on my pc. But when I sent it to two friends to test it, on one computer the microphone didn't even react and on the other one it worked fine for 10-20 seconds and then stopped working again (both laptops with just the built in microphone). This is the code:

```cs
void MicToAudioClip ( )
{
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ( );
    audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start ( Microphone.devices [ 0 ], true, 3600, AudioSettings.sampleRate );
    audioSource.Play ( );
}

void Start ( )
{
    InvokeRepeating ( "MicToAudioClip", 0, 2700 );

    AudioConfiguration audioConfiguration = AudioSettings.GetConfiguration();
    sampleRate = audioConfiguration.sampleRate;
}
```

Comment: Well you seem to have mismatched rates and stuff you reset a lot. Perhaps its just running out of places to store the cached audio

Answer (score 1):

With the Microphone.Start method, if you set it to loop, you don't need a very long length. When the audio reaches the end, it loops back around. If you neatened everything up, knowing you don't need to start the microphone again, you might end up with code that looks like this:

```cs
public AudioSource audioSource { get; private set; }
public AudioClip audioClip { get; private set; }

void Start ( )
{
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ( );
    if ( audioSource == null )
    {
        Debug.LogError ( "Could not find AudioSource component." );
        return;
    }

    audioClip = Microphone.Start ( Microphone.devices [ 0 ], true, 20, AudioSettings.GetConfiguration ( ).sampleRate );
    if ( audioClip == null )
    {
        Debug.LogError ( "Could not start the Microphone." );
        return;
    }

    // If you also want to play what's coming in on the microphone.
    audioSource.clip = audioClip;
    audioSource.Play ( );
}
```

There's also an example in the Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.Start.html) that looks very similar to the code above.

Comment: If you're also looking for some code to help with events based on the loudness of the microphone, [here's a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74075511/8051819) to a question that might help you out with that.

Comment: i changed my code to something similar like that, but now the loudness value just stopped to really change. What did i do with that now? is it just playing back the audio it recorded for the first couple seconds?

Comment: This seems to be a second question. Did you try the code above, or the code from the linked answer?

Comment: i tried the code above. and yes, it just loops the 20 seconds that it first records and then just outputs them to the audio Source, how can i fix that?

Comment: @Nachtlicht is your audiousource set to loop?

Comment: yes it is set to loop, it loops it back, so those 20 seconds just run on loop